# How to get textbox value on serverside aspx

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have an updatepanel with bootstrap modal and a textbox in it

Default.aspx:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
     <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" data-backdrop="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
             <h4>Subscribete</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
             <div class="subscription-form-container row-fluid">
               <asp:TextBox ID="UserMail" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
               <div class="success-message"></div>
               <div class="error-message"></div>
               <div class="resultado">
                 <asp:Label ID="ltl_resultado" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>                            
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" id="anchorbutton">Aceptar</a>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Default.aspx.vb:

```
Protected Sub Anchor_Click() Handles anchorbutton.ServerClick
    UpdatePanel1.Update()
    Dim Msg As String
    Msg = "Mensaje enviado desde el formulario Contactar: " & Me.UserMail.Text
End Sub
```

Here's a screenshot that shows what we have in debugger:

[image: Here´s a screenshot that shows what we have in debugger]

I've tried:

- send 
  `$('#UserMail').val()` 
  using 
  `.ajax()` 
  in markup and 
  `<WebMethod>`
  in codebehind with no results
- change `AutoEventWireup="false"` in markup and in codebehind `AddHandler` to `anchorbutton.ServerClick`
- put `anchorbutton` out of `UpdatePanel` and adding the

  ```
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="anchorbutton" />
  </Triggers>
  ```
- lots of 
  [image: Coffee]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: to get asp.net control value syntax shud be `$("#<%=UserMail.ClientID%>")`

Comment: im using `ClientIDMode="Static"` so i can use `$('#UserMail').val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was code in separate asp:Content, something related to MasterPages

Comment: discovered when trying to assign a EntityDataSource to a DropDownList, they have to exist in the same asp:Content block

Answer (score 1):

you are using UpdatePanel.Update method which
**Causes an update of the content of an UpdatePanel control**.I think this is clearing your textbox. try the below code

```
 Protected Sub Anchor_Click() Handles anchorbutton.ServerClick

        Dim Msg As String
        Msg = "Mensaje enviado desde el formulario Contactar: " & Me.UserMail.Text
        UpdatePanel1.Update()   
 End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that before, doesnt work i cant see any difference on runtime

Answer (score 1):

Using ajax you can do like below:

```
$("#<%=anchorbutton.ClientID%>").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var txtVal = $("#UserMail").val();
    console.log(txtVal);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/MyFunction",
        data: "{'textVal':'" + txtVal + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
});


[WebMethod]
public static void MyFunction(string textVal)
{

}
```

If you want to do using server side add onserverclick attribute in anchor tag:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" id="anchorbutton" OnServerClick="Anchor_Click">Aceptar</a>
```

vb code

```
Protected Sub Anchor_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    UpdatePanel1.Update()
    Dim Msg As String = Nothing
    Msg = "Mensaje enviado desde el formulario Contactar: " & Convert.ToString(Me.UserMail.Text)
End Sub
```